# AutoComplete TextField in iOS using Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, autocomplete, uitextfield

I want to implement autocompletion in a text field in my app using Objective C. I have a SQLite table in my app, so I want to search the names of user by their initials and display them as the user types in the text field.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, Add the relevant code and precisely explain what part of the process are you having problems with. No one is going to write complete module for you

Comment: Have you tried the UISearchController?

Answer (score 1):

Such a feature is achieved by basically placing a *UITableView* right under the *UITextfield* when the user begins typing.

You can detect the characters in the *textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:* method, as the user types. You can then refine the result in the *UITableview* you have placed below the *UITextfield* as the user continues typing.

When the user comes across a suitable result, he will click on a row in the UITableView. You can detect the tap in the *tableview:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:* method and set the appropriate result in the textfield.

If you do not want to spend time in building this custom component, you can simply use the one below
https://github.com/EddyBorja/MLPAutoCompleteTextField